# tabel structure for saved and removed articles

Tags: php, sql, html

I'm making a web app where users are posting their articles and other users can read them.

I wanna have a function in there where users can either save the articles that they like og remove those they don't wanna see anymore.

How should i set up my mysql tabels for that?

i'm thinking to have these tabels.

TABELS:
- articles
- users
- liked
- removed

I hope it makes sense?

Comment: It should be more like "bookmarked" and "blacklisted".

Comment: @JakubKania yes something like that, but just wanna know if there is a better way than inserting a new row each time a user decides to bookmark og blacklist an article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably build something similar to this:

[image]

Here is the SQL script to generate these tables:

```
-- tables
-- Table ArticleTypes
CREATE TABLE ArticleTypes (
    ArticleTypeId int    NOT NULL ,
    ArticleTypeDesc varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT ArticleTypes_pk PRIMARY KEY (ArticleTypeId)
);

-- Table Articles
CREATE TABLE Articles (
    ArticleId int    NOT NULL ,
    ArticleName varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    ArticleDescription varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    ArticleTypeId int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT Articles_pk PRIMARY KEY (ArticleId)
);

-- Table BookmarkStatus
CREATE TABLE BookmarkStatus (
    BookmarkStatusId int    NOT NULL ,
    BookmarkStatusDesc varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT BookmarkStatus_pk PRIMARY KEY (BookmarkStatusId)
);

-- Table Bookmarks
CREATE TABLE Bookmarks (
    BookmarkId int    NOT NULL ,
    UserId int    NOT NULL ,
    ArticleId int    NOT NULL ,
    BookmarkStatusId int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT Bookmarks_pk PRIMARY KEY (BookmarkId)
);

-- Table Users
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId int    NOT NULL ,
    UserName varchar(255)    NOT NULL ,
    UserStatus int    NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT Users_pk PRIMARY KEY (UserId)
);




-- foreign keys
-- Reference:  Articles_ArticleTypes (table: Articles)


ALTER TABLE Articles 
ADD CONSTRAINT Articles_ArticleTypes 
FOREIGN KEY Articles_ArticleTypes (ArticleTypeId)
    REFERENCES ArticleTypes (ArticleTypeId);
-- Reference:  Bookmarks_Articles (table: Bookmarks)


ALTER TABLE Bookmarks
ADD CONSTRAINT Bookmarks_Articles 
FOREIGN KEY Bookmarks_Articles (ArticleId)
    REFERENCES Articles (ArticleId);
-- Reference:  Bookmarks_BookmarkStatus (table: Bookmarks)


ALTER TABLE Bookmarks 
ADD CONSTRAINT Bookmarks_BookmarkStatus 
FOREIGN KEY Bookmarks_BookmarkStatus (BookmarkStatusId)
    REFERENCES BookmarkStatus (BookmarkStatusId);
-- Reference:  Bookmarks_Users (table: Bookmarks)


ALTER TABLE Bookmarks 
ADD CONSTRAINT Bookmarks_Users 
FOREIGN KEY Bookmarks_Users (UserId)
    REFERENCES Users (UserId);
```

Basically, you can design your `Bookmarks` table to determine if the article is `Active` or `Deleted` based on the `BookMarkStatusId` (for e.g. 1 for `Active`, 2 for `Deleted`). Your bookmarks table will handle the relationship between `users` and `articles` tables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Guess i'll go with your way :)